# how to get the value from innerXMl correctly

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, unity-game-engine, nested

I plan to retrieve each suggestion in array and then stroe it in to the list. I have trouble retrieve the option node data, in this pattern {aeroplane,aeroplanes, aerobian} {i}, Any kind soul can help me out with it.

```
XmlDocument findStringDoc = new XmlDocument();
    findStringDoc.Load (Application.dataPath+ "/" + filename);
    XmlNodeList nodeList = findStringDoc.SelectNodes("/results/error");
    //XmlNodeList suggestionNodeList = findStringDoc.SelectNodes("/results/error/suggestions/option");
    foreach(XmlNode xn in nodeList){
        errorString.Add(xn["string"].InnerText);
        errorType.Add(xn["type"].InnerText);
        //string temp = xn["suggestion"].InnerXml;

        ////TODO: Retrieve suggestions here!
        XmlNodeList suggestionNodeList = findStringDoc.SelectNodes("/suggestions");
        foreach(XmlNode yn in suggestionNodeList){
            option[suggestionNodeList.Count] = yn["option"].InnerText;
            Debug.Log(yn["option"].InnerText);
        }
        suggestionResult.Add (option);
        //Debug.Log(suggestionResult);

        //XmlNodeList suggestionNodeList = findStringDoc.SelectNodes("/results/error[string='{0}']/suggestions/option",errorString[i]);
    }


<results>
  <error>
    <string>aeroplan</string>
    <description>Spelling</description>
    <precontext>a</precontext>
    <suggestions>
        <option>aeroplane</option>
        <option>aeroplanes</option>
        <option>aerobian</option>
    </suggestions>
    <type>spelling</type>
  </error>
  <error>
    <string>i</string>
    <description>Make I uppercase</description>
    <precontext></precontext>
    <suggestions>
        <option>I</option>
    </suggestions>
    <type>grammar</type>
    <url>http://service.afterthedeadline.com/info.slp?text=i&amp;tags=PRP&amp;engine=1</url>
  </error>
</results>
```

Comment: if the string tab value is not unique, it will cause some problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`XmlDocument.SelectNodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method passing suitable XPath string parameter to select specific element(s) from `XmlDocument`, for example :

```
public void GetSuggestionOption(string keyword)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load (Application.dataPath+ "/" + filename);
    string xpath = string.Format("//error[string='{0}']/suggestions/option", keyword);
    XmlNodeList optionSuggestionList = doc.SelectNodes(xpath);
    foreach (XmlNode option in optionSuggestionList)
    {
        Debug.Log(option.InnerXml);
    }
}
```

You can call the method this way for example : `GetSuggestionOption("aeroplan")`

Comment: yup that what i want. i was think of create number of string List depend on how many number of error and inside the list of error, there is another inner list store the error suggestion option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my code below:

```
private static void GetSuggestionOption(string filename, string value, string optionSuggest)
        {
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(filename);
            var parentNode = xDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Value == value).Ancestors().FirstOrDefault();
            var childNode = parentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == optionSuggest);
            childNode.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Value));
        }
```

Calling: GetSuggestionOption(fileName, "aeroplan", "option");

Happy Coding!

Comment: sadly unity3d need to use XMLDocument due to the net.framework, anyway thank for answering.